# MyBatis: how to pass default parameter to every query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm developing a Spring Boot application and I need to pass a default parameter to every select query from a table.

This in order to get some previously encrypted user data.

Ex:

```
select
         a.ID,
         CAST(AES_DECRYPT(a.FIRST_NAME, SHA2(#{secretKey}, 512)) AS CHAR) FIRST_NAME,
         CAST(AES_DECRYPT(a.LAST_NAME, SHA2(#{secretKey}, 512)) AS CHAR) LAST_NAME,
         USERNAME,
         PASSWD,
         b.ID ID_ROLE,
         b.NAME ROLE_NAME
       from users a join
       roles b on a.ID_ROLE = b.ID
       where
        USERNAME = #{username,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```

I'm using the **mybatis-spring** library with a `SqlSessionFactoryBean` configured in this way

```
SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:sqlmaps/*.xml"));
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(ds);
        org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration = new org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration();
        configuration.getVariables().put("secretKey", "my secret key");        
        configuration.setCallSettersOnNulls(true);
        sessionFactory.setConfiguration(configuration);
        return sessionFactory;
```

But the "secretKey" It's not passed to the query.

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#{}` is for referencing parameter(s) and its properties.
To reference variables, you need to use `${}`.

As `${}` is [string substitution](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-), it must be enclosed in single quotes and it is your responsibility to escape special characters like `'` in the string.

```
SHA2('${secretKey}', 512)
```

Note that this solution is not recommended when `secretKey` is user-provided string because it is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Beware. I don't think this is a correct answer. `${}` shouldn't be used indiscriminately. It's open to SQL Injection and should be used only when you control the source of the parameter; that is, the parameter does not come from outside the code base (like the UI, a file, etc.).

Comment: In the provided code, `secretKey` is put into the configuration, so I assumed that it is not a user-provided string.

Comment: Then, all is good. Just wanted to make sure the OP won't use this strategy the wrong way.

Comment: Added a note as it's a very important point. Thank you for the comment, @TheImpaler !

Comment: @TheImpaler can confirm that the secret key is passed by configuration so It's safe